# Update string with firebase swift

Tags: swift, string, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update a string with firebase swift but I am getting an error that I do not know how to get rid of.

I have this code part that is getting an error:

```
self.dbRef.child("feed-items/\(dataPathen)/likesForPost").updateChildValues("likesForPost": "7")
```

The error I am getting is `expected "," seperator` just before the `:`. I am using dbRef in another code part so I know i works and the dataPathen is being printed just before the above code part, so that is working too.

Can anyone help me with this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change

```
self.dbRef.child("feed-items/\(dataPathen)/likesForPost").updateChildValues("likesForPost": "7")
```

**To**

```
self.dbRef.child("feed-items/\(dataPathen)/likesForPost").updateChildValues(["likesForPost": "7"])
```

And if you are only looking for incrementing a particular value at a specific node you might wanna check my answer's :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39465788/6297658, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39471374/6297658

**PS** Prefer **`runTransactionBlock:`** to update properties like `likeForPosts` as there might be a moment when two users try to like same post at the same moment (Highly Unlikely, but still a possibility...),using `updateChildValues` might end up just updating like only from one user. But **`runTransactionBlock:`** keep firing until the changes of that thread have been committed to the node

Comment: I updated to your suggestion, but when I try to use the code it said: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: I am using `.updateChildValues`, but I will try the other one I just need to figure out how to make it fit to my code.

Comment: is there anywhere, where we can chat? I have something that I hope you will help me with, since I cannot get the functionality of my like button to work the way I want to

Answer (score 1):

`updateChildValues` accepts `[AnyHashable:Any]` dictionary:

```
self.dbRef.child("feed-items/\(dataPathen)/likesForPost")
    .updateChildValues(["likesForPost": "7"])
```

Comment: I tried your code but it gives me this error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`... I also tried removing the likesForPost in the child ref but without luck

Comment: @D.Finna May be it's because `dataPathen` is `Optional`?

Comment: Could you update your question with full example including dbRef and dataPathen declaration?

Comment: Thank you for your help mixel, but I figured out using Dravidian's code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Whenever updating values at any reference in Firebase Database, you need to pass a dictionary parameter for `updateChildValues` method as `[AnyHashable: Any]` for your path reference. So just update your code of line as below:
2. `self.dbRef.child("feed-items/(dataPathen)/likesForPost").updateChildValues("likesForPost": "7")`
3. Also if you need to update more than 1 key-value pairs then you can pass those key-value pairs inside dictionary by seperating using comma as below:
4. `self.dbRef.child("feed-items/(dataPathen)/likesForPost").updateChildValues(["likesForPost": "7", "otherKey": "OtherKeyValue"])`