# FirebaseDatabase root Reference is null in Transaction

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm attempting to do a Firebase Transaction, in order to change values in two locations in my Firebase Database, but the MutableData the transaction hands me is null.

Is it forbidden to run a Transaction on the Database root? Do I have to run multiple chained transactions in order to accomplish this?

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase
    .getInstance()
    .getReference("/")

ref.runTransaction(object : Transaction.Handler {

  override fun doTransaction(currentData: MutableData): Transaction.Result {

    println( currentData) // { key = <none>, value = null }

    if (currentData.value == null){
        return Transaction.success(currentData)
    }

    currentData.child("users/{userID}/someVal/").setValue(X)
    currentData.child("items/{itemID}/someVal/").setValue(Y)
    return Transaction.success(currentData)
  }
})
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior. Your transaction handler will (almost) always first be invoked with `null`, since the client doesn't *know* the value of the location yet. Using `null` as an initial guess, makes it possible that the transaction succeeds with a single request. See Kato's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811037/data-in-transaction-is-null or mine here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578887/transcation-updatefunction-parameter-is-null/33578953#33578953

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  Very well. I now set the data if the value is null and return Transaction.success(currentData). But the doTransaction method is never called again, and the values are never set on Firebase. [gist](https://gist.github.com/jacobattwobulls/136de48822da5caa0f0113d094425a77)

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on there. But in general I'd recommend against running transactions high in your JSON tree, since they're going to hurt scalability *a lot*. Instead of using a transaction, use a multi-location update from a trusted process (such as a server you control or a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#perform_database_sanitization_and_maintenance)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask: *Is it forbidden to run a Transaction on the Database root?*  I don't find it documented anywhere, but the answer seems to be Yes.

When I run code equivalent to yours (Java instead of Kotlin) with debug log statements added, the `doTransaction()` method is invoked repeatedly and `onComplete()` reports an error of *The transaction had too many retries*.

When I change the transaction location to some child of `root`, the transaction completes successfully.

Comment: I feared as much, I guess I'll use multiple deeper transactions instead.